# Сочетание или сочетания

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, согласование

Как правильно: Е или Я? СочетаниЕ или сочетаниЯ декоров, цветов и фактур шпона с разнообразными видами отделки?

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от степени конкретности, придаваемой понятию "сочетание": можно подразумевать реально существующие сочетания, которые можно сопоставить (множественное число), а можно говорить в широком смысле о *сочетаемости* или подразумевать выбор одного сочетания из гипотетических возможностей (единственное число).

> (В альбоме) представлены разные сочетания декоров, цветов и фактур
>   шпона с разнообразными видами отделки.
>
> Что касается сочетания декоров, цветов и фактур шпона с разнообразными
>   видами отделки, есть интересные предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит только от контекста:
*сочетания (их несколько) цветов* (то есть такое, такое и эдакое и везде разных цветов), или *сочетание (одно в определенном примере) фактур*. Без контекста говорить не о чем.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, к месту или нет, но предлагаю свою подборку *сочетаний* по теме.
 Выбор ед. или мн. числа зависит от контекста и смысла. *Как пример:*

**3D-панели из МДФ в эмали, шпоне, пленке**

...Особенно эффектно выглядят объемные шпонированные панели: **сочетание** **различных форм поверхности и естественной текстуры древесины** **даёт** потрясающие результаты.

Преимущества панелей МДФ
Декоративность.
 ...Возможность отделки различными материалами (окраска, ламинирование, шпонирование), а также **сочетания различных способов отделки (шпонирование и** **окраска), позволяют** получить уникальные рисунки для создания эксклюзивных интерьеров.

...Широкий модельный ряд панелей, возможность комбинации различных рельефов и цветов, а также отличное **сочетание изделий с другими видами отделочных** **материалов — обоями, древесиной, металлом, тканью** — сделали панели МДФ привлекательными для реализации любых дизайн-проектов, в том числе разработанных по индивидуальным заказам...